# formatter select not working for FilterToolBar with jqGrid-v4.4.1

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have been using jqGrid v4.0 and it's working perfectly, but since i upgraded to jqGrid v4.4.1, the FilterTolBar does not have the select fields visible anymore.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var grid = $("#grid_container");
    grid.jqGrid({
        url:'index.php?getData=xml&',
        datatype: "xml",
        colNames:['id', 'user','sid', 'Status'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id', index:'id', width:150, hidden:true},
            {name:'user', index:'user', width:150 , stype:'select', editoptions:{value: "Jhon:Jhon;Adam:Adam"}, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']}},
            {name:'sid', index:'sid', width:65 },
            {name:'status', index:'status', width:110 },
        ],
        rowNum:20,
        rowList:[10,20,100],
        pager:'#grid_pager',
        sortname: 'user',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        height:'100%'
    })
    .jqGrid('filterToolbar' ,{searchOnEnter : true});

});
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of jqGrid is 4.4.4. If you have to use the old one you can try to include the same `value` not only in `editoptions`, but in `searchoptions` too. In case of usage `filterToolbar` it's recommended to add additional value with empty value specially for searching. It will allow not filter for the column. So the definition of `user` column could be like below

```js
{ name: 'user', stype: 'select',
    editoptions: { value: "Jhon:Jhon;Adam:Adam" },
    searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], value: ":Any;Jhon:Jhon;Adam:Adam" } }
```

You should consider to delete hidden `id` column because `id` attribute of rows (`<tr>` elements of the grid) will be assigned based on `id` attribute of the input data if your fill the data correctly (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#xml_data)). If you don't use editing of data you can remove `editoptions` and use only `searchoptions`. I strictly recommend you to use `"eq"` instead of `"cn"` for selects. The usage of `"cn"` will don't allows you to use options like `"a"`, `"ab"` and `"abc"` in one select. If the user will choose `"ab"` both `"ab"` and `"abc"` will be chosen. If the user chose `"a"` then tree options `"a"`, `"ab"` and `"abc"` will be chosen. So jqGrid will work not like the user expect it.

I recommend you additionally include `gridview: true` in all grids which you use to improve performance. The usage of `autoencode: true` is also required in the most use cases.